# Grep only for the first match in amount of files

Tags: command-line, grep

In general, I'm looking for a way to show each match of a grep command just once.

For the current usage I intend to have a list of all programmers which contributed files to a database. The files of interest are all written in java, therefor the search pattern is "@author". 
In the end, I like to get an enumeration of all shortcuts ( at this point I do not even care, in which files the pattern occur).
The result should be similar to the example below:

```
pak@Q:~$ grep -r "@author" | [...]
@bsh
@janS
@Jan Snow
...
```

edit: in case anyone is facing a similar problem, the command of interest is

> grep -rh "@author" | sort -u

Comment: What you've told us so far is ambiguous. Post concise, testable sample input and expected output or we're just guessing about what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty straightforward, you can sort and get unique entries:

```
grep [...] | sort -u
```

If you're grepping across multiple files, you'll probably want `-h` option, and perhaps `-s` to hide error messages:

## Example

For example:

```
dir
├── a
│   └── File contents:
│       @author ed
│       @author frank
│       @author ben
│     
└── b
    └── File contents:
        @author ben
        @author frank
        @author steve
```

From `dir` we run

```
$ grep -sh '@author' * | sort -u
```

Output:

```
@author ben
@author ed
@author frank
@author steve
```

## More info

### From `grep` man page:

> -h, --no-filename Suppress the prefixing of file names on output.  This is the default when there is only one file (or only standard input) to search.
>    -s, --no-messages Suppress error messages about nonexistent or unreadable files.

### From `sort` man page:

> sort - sort lines of text files
>
> - -u, --unique
>
>   with -c, check for strict ordering; without -c, output only the first of an equal run

## Credit

Thanks to [@EdMorton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton) for the `sort -u` version. Originally I suggested the following (which remains valid):

```
grep -r "author" | sort | uniq
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but that did not work for me. It seems to me, that this only works for multiple appearances in the same file.

Comment: Thank you very much for putting additional effort in helping me. Your last update actually did the trick